# Can I convert SQL Server 2008 full db to SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Recently I converted my SQL Server 2005 database to SQL Server 2008. Now I can't attach that db to SQL Server 2005. I do not have any backup of that db file as well. I have tried to generate scripts but that way i can only recover the tables. Is there any way to convert the whole database along with existing records? Please help

Comment: Simple web search returned a few artciles, this seemed most useful. http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/MSSQL_Convert_2008_To_2005.aspx or http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/11/downgrading-from-sql-2008-to-2005.aspx  Simply put it's a manual process.

Comment: I've done this in the past with generate scripts. You can script data as well in the more advanced options, although you end up with enormous scripts (had a similar problem moving databases up to Azure/Godaddy as they don't allow backups.)